# Proof Explanation - Introduction to Mathematical Logic by Samuel Buss Example III.$42$

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, first-order-logic, quantifiers

In the book *Introduction to Mathematical Logic* of Samuel Buss, example III.$42$ says:

> Assume that $\mathfrak{A}\not\vDash C[\sigma]$. (...) since $x$ is not free in $C$, $\mathfrak{A}\not\vDash C[\tau]$ for every $x$-variant $\tau$ of $\sigma$.

By contraposition, if $\mathfrak{A}\vDash C[\tau]$ for some $x$-variant $\tau$ of $\sigma$, then $\mathfrak{A}\vDash \exists x\, C[\sigma]$. However, I don't see how does this imply that $\mathfrak{A}\vDash C[\sigma]$ using that $x$ is not free in $C$. Can anybody guide me?

Comment: Intuitively, if x is not free in the formula, whatever object you assign to it the truth value of the formula for the given interpretation does not change.

Comment: Assume the simple example with $\mathbb N$ as structure and $(0=1)$ as formula. We have thatbv$\mathbb N \nvDash (0=1)[\sigma]$ for $\sigma$ whatever and this fact is not affected by the object that $\sigma$ assign to variable $x$.